# How to get Intensity Pointer of the gray Image in opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I have a binary file of 16 bit Intensity of the image. I have read this data in short array. And create 16 bit gray Image using the following code.

```
 IplImage *img=cvCreateImage( cvSize( Image_width, Image_height ), IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1 );
 cvSetData(img,Data, sizeof(short )*Image_width);
```

Where Data is short array.

Then I set ROI for this Image using this function

```
cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(crop_start.x, crop_start.y, crop_width, Image_height));
```

and ROI is being set successfully.

Now after setting the ROI I want to access the Intensity of the Image means I want pointer of the intensity of the cropped Image. I have tried this code to access the intensity

```
short *crop_Imagedata=(short *)img->imageData;
```

But This pointer is not giving the right Intensity as I have checked that by debugging the code.

Can any body please tell me how can I get pointer of the Image Intensity.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have tryed the following to find what maybe you wannt to do:

```
IplImage *img=cvCreateImage( cvSize( 15, 15 ), IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1 );
cvSet(img,cvScalar(15));//sets all values to 15

cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(4, 0, 10, 15));
short *crop_Imagedata=(short *)img->imageData;
((*crop_Imagedata) == 15) // true
```

The value that you will get is not in the roi! imageData of the IplImage structure is just a simple pointer and not a function !!! the rois of opencv is something that isn t that well documented and easy to use in my opinion. Maybe all algorithms of opencv use the rois somehow. I use them to but there is no such automatic function with the standard iplimage structure to simple use them. 
If you wannt more magic try to use the new cv::Mat object... 
but if you still wann t to use rois then you will have to allways to use

```
     CvRect roi = cvGetImageROI(img);
```

method to check all the time the position. After that you will have to add the roi offset:

```
((short*)(img->imageData + (roi.y+ypos)*img-widthStep))[roi.x+xpos]
```

remember the standard Opencv is a C library not a C++ ! btw when mixing cv::Mat rois can be a bit annoying to. To copy an iplimage to a cv::Mat without roi I have to do the following:

```
CvRect roitmp = cvGetImageROI(ilimage);
cvResetImageROI(ilimage);
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat(ilimage).clone();
cvSetImageROI(ilimage,roitmp);
```

maybe here someone knows the right way of working with rois...